# Create event for a control that doesn't support it?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can i create an event for a control that doesn't support that event.
For instance, the webBrowser doesn't have a click event, how can i create it for it?.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create events for a class from the outside. The reason being that the control itself needs to raise the event which leads to the conclusion that the event code must live inside the control. You would need to implement your own user control.

I suspect that your actual problem is that you want to intercept specific clicks on elements within the webpage that the control is displaying. To do that requires DOM programming.

Comment: "You would need to implement your own user control. As it happens, WebBrowser, by dint of being derived from System.Windows.Forms.Control" ?

Comment: Is my second paragraph a reasonable guess? Do you want to detect clicks on elements with the displayed web page?

Comment: nop actually the example i said is just an instance, i need to know how can i make an event for a control that doesnt support it? (Thanks)

Comment: Well, my first paragraph covers that. You need to write your own user control and publish the event from the inside as it were.

Comment: BTW: ["This event is not supported by this control"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.click.aspx).

Comment: @UweKeim Thanks. That was a subtlety that I failed to pick up from the documentation of the control.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force: if your event exists and has a tunnel down handler, you can hook it to the control's container.  And from there use a hit test strategy.